# xml and it's uses as web.config and web.xml in asp.net and java

Tags: xml

i am new to **xml** and web applications, i searched and read about what is xml file,and how xml files are used in configuration setting of asp.net app and web.xml for j2ee application but i need some more deep and basic knowledge about how asp.net and j2ee application get settings from these xml files and apply them on web application. can some one suggest me more deep artical about this xml files and also some other use of xml files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Java developer but .NET one, so I'm going to suggest this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CustomConfigurationSectio.aspx

Reading how to create custom configuration sections in .NET configuration files will let you learn more about how to work with them!